# Netsh, how to open ports in windows firewall for WMI?

Tags: firewall, wmi, windows-firewall, netsh

How can you open ports in windows firewall for WMI using netsh command ?

On windows vista and newer MS OS-es you run this command

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

What is netsh alternative for Win XP and 2003 ?

EDIT:
User for WMI isn't administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin

Comment: This only works if user under which WMI runs is part of administrators group. 
What if user is not administrator ?

Comment: @Primoz So you want to use an admin account or not?  I am not sure how you plan to modify the OS firewall without an admin account.  At the very least, you need to elevate to an admin account once logged in using `runas` or an equivalent, so you have confused me/us here.

Comment: I'll run this command as administrator. But for querying WMI i'll use non admin account.

Comment: Yo need to open port 135 for dcom.